# BehaviorSubject that drops the last value after it was emitted

Tags: rx-java, behaviorsubject

Anyone knows of a custom implementation of BehaviorSubject that discards the last value once a subscriber has consumed it?

Why such an implementation would be a bad idea?

Comment: Then why you are using BehaviorSubject use PublishSubject instead.

Comment: Because I would like the value to stick around until there is a subscriber.

Comment: What about multiple simultaneous subscribers, do you want all of them to receive same value when it arrives? Can single subscriber consume many values, or it unsubscribes immediately after it gets an item?

Comment: Those are valid points. Let's say I'm currently looking to have just one subscriber and this subscriber should stay subscribed and consume further emitted values.

Comment: Then BehaviorSubject is right choice for you. It will not submit last value twice to the same subscriber.

Comment: What if this subscriber unsubscribes and then subscribes again? (my case)

I would like to have a mechanism to 'consume' emitted values: if some subscriber receives a value, then discard it.

Answer (score 1):

I hacked around the issue this way:

```
<T> Observable<T> discardOnceDelivered(BehaviorSubject<T> subject) {
    return subject.filter(t -> t!=null).doOnNext(inputFields -> subject.onNext(null));
}
```

The only limitation (in Rx 1.x) is that `null` values are not accepted as valid emitted values, but rather used to encode the action of discarding the last value.